# Why does bundle exec fail but it works fine without?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm writing a simple gem and have some trouble with Bundler.

I've created a Rspec spec which runs fine with both `rspec spec` and `rake spec`.

However, if I run these commands with `bundle exec` I get an error saying my gem is not a module:

```
/Users/fiskeben/kode/waffle_cal/lib/waffle_cal/calendar.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': WaffleCal is not a module (TypeError)
    from /Users/fiskeben/kode/waffle_cal/lib/waffle_cal.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/fiskeben/kode/waffle_cal/lib/waffle_cal.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/fiskeben/kode/waffle_cal/spec/spec_helper.rb:1:in `require'
```

My gem is defined like this:

```
require 'waffle_cal/calendar'
require 'waffle_cal/event'

module WaffleCal

end
```

`calendar` and `event` implement two classes (simplified):

```
module WaffleCal

  class Calendar
    #stuff
  end
end
```

My Gemfile just contains `gemspec` and I have run `bundle install`. I also deleted `.bundle` and `Gemfile.lock` to see if it made any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. My `version.rb` declared `class WaffleCal` while other files declared `module WaffleCal`. Settling on one of them fixed the problem.